# Django: query of a foreign key of a foreign key

Tags: python, django

This might be stupid question and I am sure that there is a basic query for this situation, but I don't seem to get a hang of it and Google turned out to be a miss for solution.

I have models:

Project, primary key=project_no;

- Under project there are product_config models, primary key=id;

  - Under each product_config there is a pre_config model, primary key=product_id;

    - Under each pre_config there is a list of sub_config models, primary key=id;

Now I am loading a page for project details and I pass a project_no and make a query for all product_configs:

```
project.objects.get(project_no=project_no)

product_config.objects.filter(project_no=project_no)
```

Now I want to create a table for the list of sub_configs according to pre_config under product_config. In a shell I can query the list with:

```
config_assembly.objects.filter(product_id=product_id)
```

How I can pass the product_id of pre_config from my product_config to query all the sub_configs?

EDIT:

This is the basic structure of my models.

```
in project.models

class project(models.Model):
    project_no = IntegerField('project no', primary_key=True)

class product_config(models.Model):
    project_no = models.ForeignKey('project.project', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='project no')
    product_id = models.ForeignKey('product.pre_config', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='product code')



in product.models

class pre_config(models.Model):
    product_id = models.CharField('product code', max_length=30, unique=True, primary_key=True)

class sub_config(models.Model):
    subproduct_id = models.CharField('subproduct code', max_length=20, unique=True, primary_key=True)



in assembly.models

class config_assembly(models.Model):
    product_id = models.ForeignKey('product.pre_config', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='product code')
    subconfig_id = models.ForeignKey('product.sub_config', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='subproduct code')
```

Comment: Can you please share your models?

Comment: See the edit on my original question.

Answer (score 0):

For your use case it sounds like you want to use [the API for related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects).

If I'm understanding your question correctly, here's an example:

```py
# Of course, you should handle cases when 0 or multiple product_configs
# match the query, and replace QUERY with an actual selector.

# This is the related pre_config's product_id
my_pre_config = product_config.objects.get(QUERY).product_id

assemblies = my_pre_config.config_assembly_set.all()
```

(I follow [this standard](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#class-names) for class names, so I may be mistaken about `_set` in your case. It could be `configassembly_set`.)

You can then iterate over `assemblies` to get the sub config of each `config_assembly`, like so: `assembly.subconfig_id`.

---

Also, for the purposes of readability, I would recommend renaming your foreign key fields from `foo_id` to something signifying the actual model that the foreign key points to. For example:

```py
# models.py
class product_config(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey('project.project', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Even though the database values will be IDs, in your code you probably want to reference `my_product_config.project.project_no` instead of `my_product_config.project_no.project_no`, which can get confusing and lead to mistaking model instances for raw ID values, and vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Models I provided earlier are better named in the project, but for showing the case a made a mock-up of the structure, so naming is bad.

I got the query work, but it returns multiple objects, as I knew would happen. I am trying to render from the query a list of items for each object returned in my template. Is there way to do so?

I've been trying to google it all night last night, but couldn't find a decent example that would fit my case.

Comment: I am rendering the table inside my template with basic for loop {% for i in assemblies%} and I can render out the complete list of assemblies from assemblies.objects.all(). Is there way to filter the for loop based on another loop from {% for i in porduct_configs%}, from which I get the correct product_id for a filter?

Comment: To summarize, you're trying to get the assemblies of the `pre_config`, and `product_id` is already known, right? If so, `.config_assembly_set.all()` in my answer should work, as it gets the config_assemblies tied to an individual pre_config, which is identified by a `product_id`. Alternatively, `config_assembly.objects.filter(product_id=product_id)`.

Comment: Or are you looking for something like this?
`{% for product in product_configs %}{% for assembly in product.product_id.config_assembly_set.all %}{# do something with assembly #}{% endfor %}{% endfor %}`